# Android SeekBar Thumb Image change on Normal , on pressed , on release

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to Implement different Images on SeekBar movement It work fine for on first load(white image) and (on pressed -- yellow image) but (on press release -- blue image) is not showing. Here is my code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_seek_thumb_pressed_new" 
        android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_seek_thumb_selected_new" 
        android:state_selected="false" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_seek_thumb_normal_new"/>

</selector>
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: did you try without the window focused element?

Answer (score 0):

When you release the button, it will revert back to the deault state. If you want a different image when you lift your finger from the button, try

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_seek_thumb_selected_new" 
    android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
```

instead of

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_seek_thumb_selected_new" 
    android:state_selected="false" />
```